# Endless XHR request with useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, crud, use-effect, mern

So I just made a simple CRUD application, I have a little issue with the useEffect hook, I want to rerender the list of posts fetched from the database whenever I submit a new post, so I thought to include the "fetchData" useState variable as a dependency for the useEffect, but it ended in an endless loop of xhr requests.
Here is the code

```
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [content, setContent] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/posts");
        setFetchedData(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [fetchedData]);

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title.length > 5 && content.length > 10) {
      try {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/posts", { title, content });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      alert(
        `You entered ${title.length} characters for the title and ${content.length} characters for the content of the post. Title must be at least 5 characters long and content at least 10`
      );
    }
  };
```

As you see I use fetchedData as an dependency for the useEffect so whenever the fetchData changes I rerender the whole list of posts, where when I think about it doesn't really make that much sense, anyone got a suggestion on how to rerender the list of posts whenever I submit a new post? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the infinite loop is to not rely on the state change to fetch new data -
Extract the fetch into a separate function, call it once on component mount, then call it from your `onSubmit` everytime a post is successfully created:

```js
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/posts");
    setFetchedData(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(); // call once
}, []);

const onSubmit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (title.length > 5 && content.length > 10) {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/posts", {title, content});
      fetchData(); // call after new post is created
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  } else {
    alert(
      `You entered ${title.length} characters for the title and ${content.length} characters for the content of the post. Title must be at least 5 characters long and content at least 10`
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot ^_^
Looks like such a simple solution